# Conditional probability against sum of two normal random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability

I am trying to solve the following problem:

Let $X$, $Y$ be two variables with the distribution $\mathcal{N}(0,\lambda^2)$. Find the distribution of $X$ under the condtion $X+Y=t$.

So what we are looking for is, for $B$ a Borel set, the following thing:
$$
P(X\in B\:|\:X+Y=t)
$$
But $$P(X\in B\:|\:X+Y=t)=P(Y\in t-B)=\int_{t-B}\frac{1}{\lambda\sqrt{2\pi}}e^\frac{-x^2}{2\lambda^2}dx.$$

By the change of variables, the last integral is equal to
$$
-\int_{B}\frac{1}{\lambda\sqrt{2\pi}}e^\frac{-(y-t)^2}{2\lambda^2}dy.
$$
This would mean that the distribution of $X|X+Y=t$ is $\mathcal{N}(t,\lambda^2)$ BUT:

1. There is unexpected minus sign, which makes a measure of the set negative. I suppose it comes from wrong change of variables?
2. The answer in the textbook is that this distribution is $\mathcal{N}(t/2, \lambda^2/2)$. So where is the mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's another way.  I'm assuming $X$and $Y$ are independent. 
Since $\begin{pmatrix}X\\X+Y\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0\\ 1 & 1\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}X\\Y\end{pmatrix}$, the joint distribution of $(X,X+Y)$ is  $\mathcal N_2\left(0,\lambda^2 \begin{pmatrix}1 & 1\\ 1 & 2\end{pmatrix}\right)$.

Note also that the distribution of $X+Y$ is $\mathcal N(0,2\lambda^2)$.
By Bayes' theorem, the conditional density of $X$ given $X+Y=t$ is given by
$$\begin{aligned}f_{X|X+Y=t}(x) 
= \frac{f_{(X,X+Y)}(x,t)}{f_{X+Y}(t)}
&\propto\exp\left(-\frac 1{2\lambda^2} (x,t)\begin{pmatrix}2 & -1\\ -1 & 1\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}x\\t\end{pmatrix}\right)\\
&\propto \exp\left(-\frac{1}{\lambda^2} (x^2-tx)\right) \\
&\propto \exp\left(-\frac{1}{2 \frac{\lambda^2}2} (x-\frac t2)^2\right) \end{aligned}$$
$\propto$ means proportional, which allows me to drop multiplicative factors that do not depend on $x$.

Given the final expression, $f_{X|X+Y=t}(x) $ is the density of $\mathcal N(\frac t2, \frac{\lambda^2}2)$, as claimed in your textbook.

Comment: Seems very plausible to me, but tI don't understand one thing. From my calculations $(X, X+Y)$ should have the distribution $\mathcal{N}(0, \lambda^2\left(\begin{array}{cc} 2 & -1 \\ -1 & 1\end{array}\right) )$, since the random variable $Z=TX$, where $X=(X_1,\ldots, X_n)$ are independent normal variables has the distribuiton $\mathcal{N}(m, Q)$ where $Q=(T^{-1})^tT^{-1}$. How does it relate to your answer?

Comment: @IgorSikora If $Z\in \mathbb R^n$ is a random vector with distribution $\mathcal N_n(\mu, \Sigma)$,  and $A\in \mathbb R^{m\times n}$, the distribution of $AZ$ is $\mathcal N_m(A\mu, A\Sigma A^T)$. Here $$A\Sigma A^T = \lambda^2 \begin{pmatrix}1 & 1\\ 1 & 2\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: @IgorSikora you got the wrong formula, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Affine_transformation

Comment: Ok, I see now - but that's interesting, because on Wikipedia it says that $\mathcal{N}(\mu ,\Sigma ) $ means that $\Sigma$ is a covariance matrix, but in my textbook it clearly states that $\Sigma$ is a matrix *inverse* to covariance matrix. Some historical issues?

Comment: @IgorSikora What's the language of this textbook ? I've never seen $\Sigma$ denoting the inverse of the covariance matrix. What do they say in the one-dimensional case ? Even in this textbook $\mathcal N(0,\sigma^2)$ surely means that the variance is $\sigma^2$. It'd be very odd to deviate from the norm...

Comment: It's Polish textbook, very popular one. I assume they might follow some old, Russian notation (but this is only a speculation). And yes, in the one-dimensional case $\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)$ has variance $\sigma^2$. I suppose that it comes from the formula for the density function - in "wiki" notation I still have to find the inverse of $\Sigma$, whereas in "textbook" notation I have it immediately.

Comment: Both the [Polish](https://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wielowymiarowy_rozk%C5%82ad_normalny) and [Russian](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5) Wikipedia denote the covariance matrix as $\Sigma$. Once you're done with this textbook, it's best that you forget its notations :)